# Prove that there exist $a,b\in A$ such that $d(a,b)=\sup{\{d(x,y)\mid x,y\in A\}}$ if $A$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$ be a compact subset. Prove that there exist $a,b\in A$ such that $$d(a,b)=\sup{\{d(x,y)\mid x,y\in A\}}$$

I think this is intuitively obvious but I don't know how to prove it. I know that if A is compact , then A is closed and bounded. the "closed" property makes sure that I can find two points in A such that $d(a,b)=\text{diam}(A)$.

Comment: To do it formally you may show that $d(x,y)$ is continuous and hence by Weierstrass it attains a $\max$ in $A$. Metrics are continuous, yes?

Answer (score 2):

$d:A\times A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $d(x,y)$ is a continuous function. Since $A\times A$ is compact (Tichonof) it attains its maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s:= \sup\{d(x,y)|x,y\in A\}$. Then there are  sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ in $A$ such that

$d(x_n,y_n) \to s$.

Since $A$ is compact, $(x_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ with limit $a \in A$.

Again, since $A$ is compact, $(y_{n_{k}})$ contains a convergent subsequence $(y_{n_{k_j}})$ with limit $b \in A$.

Then we get:

$$d(a,b)= \lim_{j \to \infty}d(x_{n_{k_j}},y_{n_{k_j}})=s.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let it be that $x_n,y_n\in A$ with $d(x_n,y_n)\to\sup\{d(x,y)\mid x,y\in A\}$

Every sequence in compact $A^2$ has a convergent subsequence that has a limit in $A^2$.

If $\langle a,b\rangle\in A^2$ is such a limit then evidently $$d(a,b)=\sup\{d(x,y)\mid x,y\in A\}$$